# Android phone keeps rebooting, how can I save my data?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, backup, reboot, data-transfer, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

I hope this question fits this site, as in my opinion the problem is caused by Android.

My problem is that my phone froze all of the sudden while browsing settings, and ever since the first freeze it reboots all the time. It boots just fine, but after a short period it freezes then reboots again, in a loop.

I tried to leave my phone until the battery drains, then take it out for a day, but the issue is still present. I wiped the cache partition from recovery mode, the reboot is still occurs even in safe mode.

**UPDATE:** **Safe mode seems to be working, at least I can browse my phone without it freezing. However it freezes in safe mode if I go to the "Application manager" in settings, thus I can't uninstall any applications.**

I've read that a hard (factory) reset would probably solve the problem, however I have important information on my phone (contacts, messages, pictures) which I don't want to lose.

Since I assume that the hard reset would solve my problem, my question is, how can I save my data from the phone? Is there any utility that allows me to directly copy from the phone?

- **Phone:** Samsung Galaxy Ace 2 (i8160)
- **Android version:** 4.1.2
- **Kernel version:**  3.0.31-1106830

The phone is **not rooted** or tinkered with in any way.

I know there are already similar question on this site, however they did not receive a working answer, and I feel like my situation might be a different issue.

Comment: Data cable and grab files to PC?

Comment: Does not work, because the phone will reboot shortly after boot. Kies does not even recognize the device under this short time it's turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but at this point your only hope is a factory reset.

The symptoms sound like the data for one of the system apps has become corrupted. If you had any way to stop the reboot cycle, you'd have a shot at saving the data. Since even safe mode doesn't give you that, there's not much you can do.

I will suggest, for the future, saving all of your contacts, messages, phone logs, *et al.*, to external servers, such as Google Contacts. That will also help when you upgrade your phone. There are several apps in the Google Play store to save text messages, phone logs, photos, videos, and the like to a remote server.

Comment: Please read my update, it won't reboot in safe mode, only if unlock the screen.

Comment: I saw that. In order to be able to save any of the data, though, you'll have to unlock your screen.